YAML get current date
I'm trying to get the current date in YAML. This will be
id: 'check_validity'
data: 'test'
date: now()

and then use this as a reference further down in my code.

YAML is data structure, just like JSON or XML. There is nothing executed there. now() must be parsed by your Yaml parser, that you do not specify here.
